# sqlite - register_converters don't trigger on Python NoneType?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np

def convert_int(x):
    print('convert_int was called with {}'.format(x))
    if x == b'None' or x == b'':
        return -1    # minus 1 as placeholder for integer nan
    return np.int64(np.float64(x))  # np.float64 needed here as int(b'4.0') throws 

sqlite3.register_converter('int', convert_int)
sqlite3.register_converter('None', convert_int)  # attempt to tigger upon None
sqlite3.register_converter('NoneType', convert_int) # attempt to tigger upon None
sqlite3.register_converter('null', convert_int) # attempt to tigger upon None

values = [(4.0,), (4,), (None,), ('',), (1.0,)]  #

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
conn.execute("create table test(p int)")
conn.executemany("insert into test(p) values (?)", values)

print(list(conn.execute("select p from test")))
```

yields the following output:

```
convert_int was called with b'4'
convert_int was called with b'4'
convert_int was called with b'1'
Out[2]: 
[(4,), (4,), (None,), (None,), (1,)]  #
```

convert_int() is only called 3 times for the non-None type entries?
What's the required converter I need to register in order to convert/parse the other 2 None types to some alternative value?
My attempts above unfortunately don't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how [the `_pysqlite_fetch_one_row()` function in Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c#L264) handles a value to be converted:

```c
if (converter != Py_None) {
    nbytes = sqlite3_column_bytes(self->statement->st, i);
    val_str = (const char*)sqlite3_column_blob(self->statement->st, i);
    if (!val_str) {
        Py_INCREF(Py_None);
        converted = Py_None;
    } else {
        item = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(val_str, nbytes);
        if (!item)
            goto error;
        converted = PyObject_CallFunction(converter, "O", item);
        Py_DECREF(item);
        if (!converted)
            break;
    }
}
```

The [`sqlite3_column_blob()` function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) returns `NULL` for an SQL `NULL` value; in this case, the `if (!val_str)` branch returns a `None` value without calling the converter.

So it is not possible to convert NULL values to anything else.

Converters are intended to add support for other data types. If you want to get values that are not actually in the database, change your query:

```sql
SELECT ifnull(p, -1) AS "p [int]" FROM test;
```

(Without a bare table column, this also requires `PARSE_COLNAMES`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This concludes my puzzle, will use IFNULL as suggested.